# PHP. Is it possible to redeclare non-abstract method as abstract?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

Key class has a non-abstract method getDescription() (for many purposes).

Key class is extended by (one of) "a child abstract class".

"A child abstract class" is extended by "a concrete class".

I want to **force** "a concrete class" to implement getDescription() method and try to redeclare it in "a child abstract class" as an abstract method, but fail.

So, is it possible to redeclare non-abstract method as abstract in php?
If not - how to **force** a concrete method to be implemented?

*The key class. I need getDescription as declared in this way for many purposes.*

```
abstract class beverage{
public $description = "Unknown beverage";
public function getDescription(){return $this->description;}
};
```

*The abstract class, overriden getDescription() - but does not work.*

```
abstract class condimentDecorator extends beverage {
    //public abstract function getDescription();
};
```

*Concrete class, which MUST reimpliment getDescription.*

```
class milk extends condimentDecorator{
public $beverage;
public function __construct(beverage $beverage){$this->beverage = $beverage;}
public function getDescription(){return $this->beverage->getDescription().", Milk";}
};
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to redeclare non-abstract method as abstract in php?

No, you can't do that in *PHP*

---

It seems that you are trying to implement a ***Decorator*** pattern.
In such case the presented classes chain is over-complicated.
*Decorator* pattern is dedicated to add(extend) functionality to another class without changing its structure.
The following is a classical and more optimal approach of implementing *decorators*:

```
abstract class Beverage {
    public $description = "Unknown beverage";

    public function getDescription(){
        return $this->description;
    }
}

class CondimentDecorator extends Beverage {
    protected $beverage;

    public function __construct(Beverage $beverage) {
        $this->beverage = $beverage;
    }

    public function getDescription() {
        return "Description:\t" . $this->beverage->getDescription() . " with condiment";
    }
};

class Milk extends Beverage {
    public function __construct($desc = "") {
        $this->description = $desc;
    }
}

$milk = new Milk('Milk beverage');
$milk_with_condiment = new CondimentDecorator($milk);
echo $milk_with_condiment->getDescription();
```

The output:

```
Description:    Milk beverage with condiment
```

Comment: Still, the key question remains: "is it possible to redeclare concrete method as abstract in php"?

Comment: such redeclaration of "concrete to abstract" is possible in java, however.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is how you're implementing this.

If you've an class that already implements a method all it's children will by default implement it.

So lets say you've the following:

```
Class A {
    public function niceFunction() {return "some awesome return with   potato"; }
}

Class B  extends A{
     //it already has niceFunction
}
Class Avocado extends B {
   // it also already has NiceFunction
}
```

So what you want to do is overwrite the default function.

I think you should take a time and re-think if the structure is correct.

The condimentDecorator couldn't be a interface?

Editd:

My suggestion would be do something Like this:

```
Interface Descritible()
{
   public function getDescription();
}

class beverage implements Descritible{
 //do the stuff you need to do
 // It must have getDescription() cuz it implements Descritible
}

abstract  class A implements Descritible{}

class Avocado extends A {
  //It'll not have a default implementation of getDescription
  //so it'll have to implement it.
}
```

So then the Class avocado will need to implements getDescription as Beverage would've as well, and you should be conflict free.

Comment: I thought of using an interface, did not try, but have a feeling that it will also lead to a conflict.
The beverage class has to have concrete getDescription(); defining an interface for a child class with the same method as in parent already sounds not good. The abstraction problem (i.e., redeclaring concrete to abstract) will still remain.

Comment: My suggestion would be do something Like this: